# Model won't update in Angular 2 radio list

Tags: javascript, web-component, angular

I'm trying to build a Angular 2 component which displays a list of options with radios. It works fine but it the `answer` field of the component, which is bound inside `[(ng-model)]="answer"`, won't update when selecting one of the options. Am I doing something wrong or isn't this the way to create a list of radio selection options?

```
  <div>
    Answer: {{ answer }}
  </div>
  <div class="radio" *ng-for="#option of itemData">
      <label>
          <input type="radio" [value]="option.id" [(ng-model)]="answer"
                 (change)="responseChanged()" name="radio-list">
          <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
      </label>
  </div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Iw4dkq0QhjhmxbidA6O5?p=preview)

Comment: Here's a [custom implementation](https://github.com/barbatus/ng2-pipes/blob/master/client/lib/radio_value_accessor.ts) for radio, don't know about lists though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well i guess two way binding is now working with radio, so currently you cannot use `[(ng-model)]`.

The alternative is to use the change event and checked attribute. See my plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/7Zm3qgoSv22Y9KrBn4tS?p=preview

`(change)="answer=$event.target.value"`

and

`[checked]='answer==option.id'`

Comment: I was assuming this too :) I wonder if there's a way to build this kind of radio list using the Control class inside the Component.

Comment: Well, it looks like there are other issues related to properties being bound to the view: `setAnswer(e) {
        this.items[e.index].answer = e.answer; // e.answer = "b"
        console.log(this.items[e.index]);  // the "answer" field of the object is undefined
    }`

Comment: OK, property bindings, `[item-data]='item'`, send a reference down the component tree, to which the 'answer' is set to an empty string by [(ng-model)] and this is what makes the top level component's `setAnswer` handler show the answer field as undefined after it's being updated in the line above.

Comment: Using Beta 16 and this solution still works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use ng-model with radio boxes like in angular1. However there are several components on github that allows you to do it easily, like [ng2-radio-group](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-radio-group) component. It has support for both radio select and multiple checkboxes select:

```
<radio-group [(ngModel)]="sortBy">
    <input type="radio" value="rating"> Rating<br/>
    <input type="radio" value="date"> Date<br/>
    <input type="radio" value="watches"> Watch count<br/>
    <input type="radio" value="comments"> Comment count<br/>
</radio-group>


<checkbox-group [(ngModel)]="orderBy">
    <input type="checkbox" value="rating"> Rating<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="date"> Date<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="watches"> Watch count<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="comments"> Comment count<br/>
</checkbox-group>
```