# Angular 2.1, radio button not updating on load

Tags: angular, radio-button

For angular 2.1 - the radio button is not set even though the property in my interview variable is set and not null.

I have tried to look at the following posts and tried almost every solution but without any luck.

[Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding)
[Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368683/model-wont-update-in-angular-2-radio-list)

**First setup**

This one works when changing between the radio buttons, but it doesn't set the selected radio button upon load.

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="interview.interviewChannelType" name="interviewChannelTypePersonal" value="0" [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 0"
                                id="interviewChannelTypePersonal" required />
<label for="interviewChannelTypePersonal">Personlig møde</label>
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="interview.interviewChannelType" name="interviewChannelTypePhone" value="1" [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 1"
                                id="interviewChannelTypePhone" required />
<label for="interviewChannelTypePhone">Telefon</label>
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="interview.interviewChannelType" name="interviewChannelTypeVideo" value="2" [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 2"
                                id="interviewChannelTypeVideo" required />
<label for="interviewChannelTypeVideo">Video</label>
```

**Second try**

This checks the selected radio button upon load but it wont let me navigate between the radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" (change)="interview.interviewChannelType = $event.target.value" [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 0" value="0" />
<label for="interviewChannelTypePersonal">Personlig møde</label>
<input type="radio" (change)="interview.interviewChannelType = $event.target.value" [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 1" value="1" />
<label for="interviewChannelTypePhone">Telefon</label>
<input type="radio" (change)="interview.interviewChannelType = $event.target.value" [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 2" value="2" />
<label for="interviewChannelTypeVideo">Video</label>
```

interveiwChannelType is an enum:

```
export enum InterviewChannelType {
Personal = 0,
Phone = 1,
Video = 2
}
```

I hope some of you out there can give me a boost in the right direction! Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION FOUND**

Thanks to HirenParekh's comment, he made me aware of using the value as a angular property instead of the normal attribue. Changing it from `value="0"` to `[value]="0"` did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the value property of radio button. Inside your first setup bind the value property as follows.

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="interview.interviewChannelType" 
                    name="interviewChannelTypePersonal" 
                    [value]="InterviewChannelType.Personal" 
                    [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 0"
                    id="interviewChannelTypePersonal" required 
/>
<label for="interviewChannelTypePersonal">Personlig møde</label>
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="interview.interviewChannelType" 
                    name="interviewChannelTypePhone" 
                    [value]="InterviewChannelType.Phone"  
                    [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 1"
                    id="interviewChannelTypePhone" required 
/>
<label for="interviewChannelTypePhone">Telefon</label>
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="interview.interviewChannelType" 
                    name="interviewChannelTypeVideo" 
                    [value]="InterviewChannelType.Video"  
                    [checked]="interview.interviewChannelType === 2"
                    id="interviewChannelTypeVideo" required 
/>
<label for="interviewChannelTypeVideo">Video</label>
```

Comment: Angular cannot read an enum directly in html. I am receiving a "cannot read Personal of undefined". Changing the value property to [value]="0" works. Thank you for making me aware of changing the value attribute to a property.